# create list of products from array by class Product, then save in local storage

Tags: javascript

This is a class that generates a list of products from an array of objects. I need to print in a paragraph tag the value of this.total when button plus() and menos() are clicked. I try totalnum.textContent = this.total, but the element is fixed to 0. Then i want to store that data into the local storage. Thanks in advance.

```js
var returnedFromDB = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Almendras', price: 25},
        {id: 2, name: 'Nueces', price: 10},
        {id: 3, name: 'Mermelada', price: 15},
        {id: 4, name: 'Alfajor', price: 20}
];

    
class Product {
  constructor(obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
    this.total = 0;

    const div = document.createElement('div');
    const button1 = document.createElement('button');
    const button2 = document.createElement('button');
    const p1 = document.createElement('p');
    const p2 = document.createElement('p');
    const totalnum = document.createElement('p');

    button1.textContent = '+';
    button1.onclick = this.plus.bind(this);
    
    button2.textContent = '-';
    button2.onclick = this.menos.bind(this);
    
    p1.textContent = this.obj.name;
    p2.textContent = this.obj.price;

    totalnum.textContent = this.total;
 
    document.getElementById('products').appendChild(div);
    div.appendChild(p1);
    div.appendChild(p2);
    div.appendChild(button1);
    div.appendChild(totalnum);
    div.appendChild(button2);
  }

  plus() {
    this.total++;
    console.log(this.obj.price, this.total);
  }

  menos() {
    this.total > 0 ? this.total-- : 0;
    console.log(this.obj.price, this.total);
  }
}


let productList = [];
for (let i = 0; i < returnedFromDB.length; i++) {
  productList[i] = new Product(returnedFromDB[i]);
}
```

```html
<section id="products"></section>
```

Comment: Like the error states `total` is not defined. From your snippet I guess you meant `this.total`.

Comment: thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var returnedFromDB = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Almendras', price: 25},
        {id: 2, name: 'Nueces', price: 10},
        {id: 3, name: 'Mermelada', price: 15},
        {id: 4, name: 'Alfajor', price: 20}
];

    
class Product {
  constructor(obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
    this.total = 0;

    const div = document.createElement('div');
    const button1 = document.createElement('button');
    const button2 = document.createElement('button');
    const p1 = document.createElement('p');
    const p2 = document.createElement('p');

    button1.textContent = '+';
    button1.onclick = this.plus.bind(this);
    
    button2.textContent = '-';
    button2.onclick = this.minus.bind(this);
    
    p1.textContent = this.obj.name;
    p2.textContent = this.obj.price;

    document.getElementById('products').appendChild(div);
    div.appendChild(p1);
    div.appendChild(p2);
    div.appendChild(button1);
    div.appendChild(button2);
  }

  plus() {
    this.total++;
    console.log(this.obj.price, this.total);
  }

  minus() {
    this.total--;
    console.log(this.obj.price);
  }
}


let productList = [];
for (let i = 0; i < returnedFromDB.length; i++) {
  productList[i] = new Product(returnedFromDB[i]);
}
```

```html
<div id="products"></div>
```

You missed the "this" before the total, because you want "this"(the class) total property.